# router.patch is returning 404 "not found"

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on small node api and I have an issue with patch method.
My router.patch is returning me 404.

This is how my route looks:

```
router.param('userId', findById);

router.patch(
  '/api/projects/update/:projectId/:userId',
  authCheck,
  isAdmin,
  findProjectById,
  update
);
```

The `findById` is based on my :userId param. Whole method looks like this:

```
exports.findById = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });
    }
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};
```

Based on that I should get proper user for proper project.

My two ayhorization methods:

```
exports.authCheck = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    /* get token from header
    replace('Bearer', '') - this will remove bearer from token header
    */

    const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer', '');

    //check if no token
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied' });
    }

    /*
    decoded contains _id as a payload in token. Id is from getAuthToken */
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
    const user = await User.findOne({
      _id: decoded._id,
      'tokens.token': token,
    });

    if (!user) {
      throw new Error();
    }
    req.token = token;
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Please authenticate' });
  }
};

exports.isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.user.role !== config.get('roleSecret')) {
      return res.status(403).json({
        errors: [
          {
            msg: 'No Admin rights. Access Denied!!',
          },
        ],
      });
    }
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(403).json({ msg: 'Forbidden access' });
  }
};
```

Finaly, my project controller where i have `findProjectById, update`
In `findProjectById` I am looking for project based on route param and i assing it to `project`

```
exports.findProjectById = async (req, res, next) => {
  const _id = req.params.projectId;
  try {
    let project = await Project.findById(_id);
    if (!project) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Porject not found' });
    req.project = project;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Porject not found' });
    }
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};
```

My update method i s not done, because i was testing if anything heppens

```
exports.update = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const proj = await req.project;
    const _id = proj._id;
    await Project.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, req.body, {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    });
    if (!proj) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Project not found' });
    }
    return res.json(proj);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};
```

Not sure what am I missing here, but after few hours and lot of searching still can't get this working

Answer (score 0):

Get this working. Issue was in my router path.

`/api/projects/update/:projectId/:userId`
Should be
`/projects/update/:projectId/:userId`

this can be closed